# Search in column that has array(value1,value2,...) in sql table

Tags: php, sql

I have a sql table called "Offres" 
inside this table a column named "regions" has array in it  (value1, value2, value3,...)
row1 :"35,2,15,69,98"
row2 :"7,9,15,5,69"
row3 :"7,3,45,5,6"
how can I search rows which has multiple value in same time
for exp : I want to search rows which has 15,69 in it 
the result should display  row1 and row2
thanks

[image]

Comment: you can use like in your sql query

Comment: is this a set column or an actual varchar with comma seperated values? for the latter you could use a like-comparison in the select statement otherwise look here for operations on set-columns http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/set.html

Comment: You could try it with regular expressions (which would also fix all of the problems described with LIKE below), but this will slow down your queries. Convert your table structure like [juergen d](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18654656/1682509) described it and learn something about [database normalization](http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm). This will solve your problem.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

---

> for exp : I want to search rows which has 15,69 in it

---

if you can add spaces before and after your values, then it might be easy check [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e18e1/1)

like

```
row1 :' 690 , 6969 , 069 , 69069 '
row2 :' 69 , 69 , 69 , 69 , 69 '
row3 :' 6969 , 69 , 69069 '
row4 :' 069 , 69069 '
row5 :' 69 '

    SELECT * FROM Offres WHERE regions LIKE regions LIKE '% 69 %';
```

Comment: in like query some value are wrong, like if I want to display rows with value "1" all rows with value 1... are displayed like "10,11,12,13,..."

Comment: just make the like more explicit you would need to look for `value LIKE '69,%' OR value LIKE '%,69' OR value = '69'` and combine that with `AND` and all other restrictions you need also to be true for that row

Comment: @DrCopyPaste but I am confused now, what if the value in row would be ,6969,

Comment: `value LIKE '69,%' OR value LIKE '%,69' OR value = '69'` also matches numbers like 690, 691 or 169, 269... --> doesn't work, too

Comment: thanks but still doesn't work for "1"
if I do value LIKE '1,%' OR value LIKE '%,1' OR value = '1' 
still display 10,11.....
the value are from 1 to 99

Comment: no it should not, because the % is where it is matching every character in any count look at the three different selects here where i demonstrate that http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3873d/3

Comment: then i do not understand why it works that way in my fiddle, hmm mind setting up your example there so we can have a look?

Comment: You do write OR value LIKE '%,1' so it can begin with "1"

Comment: yes and must END with 1 also so no further digits should be allowed there did you see my sqlfiddle?

Comment: @DrCopyPaste: Have a look here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/15fef/1 Your query matches the third row, but it shouldn't

Comment: that is because you now have more values inside you need to include the comma in the like also, and then it is not returned http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/15fef/2

Comment: Yes I see your sqlfiddle but what you did there is an OR not an AND so ever it begin with '1' or end with '1'

Comment: in the last link , the result is empty

Comment: that was the point now wasnt it? because the exact value "69" is not inside the table ;)

Comment: I added a picture of my DB

Comment: @moumouh206 did you find any appropriate answer ?

Comment: I found solution like :p
I added in all rows '0,' in beginning of each value and ',0' in the end 
like that I can search with '%,value,%' any value I want , and it return always a correct value :)

Comment: this answer should be edited then to match what you did, because currently it is misleading to others that come here later

Comment: @DrCopyPaste well that would also be a misleading thing, giving a suggestion like adding zeroes in start and end to cope the problem

Comment: i agree, i actually have an update to the fiddle i posted before to clarify what you have to be aware of when looking for such values with like, i let out one additional comparison in the last fiddle, this one should cover all possiblities where a value can occur in the column (alone, at first, at last, in between) http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/35e66/1

Comment: but the query you post now does not match your fiddle you link to. Besides I still think the last fiddle i posted is more like what should be done here, no adding stuff to the values...http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/35e66/1 or see this one if you want to see how to look for two values at once http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/305b81/2

Answer (score 5):

### Never, never, never store multiple values in one column!

As you see now this will only result in problems. Please normalize your DB structure first like this

```
Offers
id   region
1    35
1    2
1    15
...
2    7
2    9
2    15
...
```

Comment: @moumouh206: Since your probably using MySQL you can use [find_in_set()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

Answer (score 0):

If you intend for a field to be searchable via SQL, store it as multiple rows and do not serialize it.

If some reasons, you have to, you may have to extract out each row, deserialize it (for your case, with `explode()`, and match it singularly, which takes up lots of processing power.

Answer (score 0):

You can search for elements within such lists with FIND_IN_SET().
If you need to find multiple entries within the rows, you need multiple selects.

But: Good database structures would avoid all this and have only one entry per row instead of lists

Answer (score -1):

For the sake of completeness I am posting this as an answer, too, so it does not get lost in the huge discussion in the comments ;)

First of all, if you want to have multiple values in one column in SQL the set-column is the way to go. See for example [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/constraint-enum.html) and [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/set.html). But if you absolutely cannot get around having multiple values in one column and you can guarantee, that they will always occur in the same pattern (comma-separated, no spaces), then you can search for rows that contain 2 specific such values you can do it like this (according to your example)

```
SELECT * FROM Offres WHERE
  (
      regions = '15' /*value is the only one in that row, obviously this is not necessary if you look for 2 values at once, but if you would only look for one value at once you MUST include it ;)*/
    OR regions LIKE '%,15' /*value is the last value in that row*/
    OR regions LIKE '15,%' /*value is the first value in that row*/
    OR regions LIKE '%,15,%' /*value is a value somewhere in between other values in that row*/
  )
  AND
  (
      regions = '69' /*value is the only one in that row, obviously this is not necessary if you look for 2 values at once, but if you would only look for one value at once you MUST include it ;)*/
    OR regions LIKE '%,69' /*value is the last value in that row*/
    OR regions LIKE '69,%' /*value is the first value in that row*/
    OR regions LIKE '%,69,%' /*value is a value somewhere in between other values in that row*/
  )
```

You can also try that out in this [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/64a4eb/2).