# Which query would be more optimal?

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design, laravel-4

Currently we have have following combined different data i.e one with comma separated and one without comma separated in same table.

**#1**

```
id | values    
------------   
1  | 1,2,3
2  | 4,5,6
3  | 7,8,9
4  | 1
5  | 2
6  | 3
7  | 4
8  | 5
```

Let's say I want to search value `1` from the table and count it. Which is the most optimal way of querying for such kind of data structure ? Is it using :

- `WHERE value =`
- `WHERE value LIKE`
- `WHERE value IN`

Or Do I need to change my database and have all values to be in same format ?

Any help or advice on best practices would be appreciated.

Comment: `WHERE with "="` and `WHERE IN` is *much* faster than `WHERE with "LIKE"`

Comment: also remember doing like 1 will match "1,11,12,13,14,15,etcetcetc"

Comment: @Dave: There are ways to match the correct values, but it's damn ugly: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18657144/1682509

Comment: sub likes with or switches are a horrible solution to the like problem.  Much better to normalise the data into a contents table and an index table as Juergen says

Answer (score 1):

### Never store multiple values in one column!

Please normalize your data. That makes it way easier to query and it is also faster and can make use of indexes.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that normalizing your data is the way to go to get optimal performance. But not changing the schemma, you can't really use `=` because you may have multiple numbers. One way to count the number of occurrences for 1 in those comma separated values is using [FIND_IN_SET()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```sql
SELECT SUM(CASE 
      WHEN FIND_IN_SET(1, `values`)
        THEN 1
      ELSE 0
      END) AS count1
FROM tab1
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/44ab0/1)</kbd>

Comment: Out of interest I would assume the query overhead for doing this is massive ?

Comment: I'm sure this isn't the best approach for performance, no. This wouldn't take advantage of indexes.